# Rails 3: MongoDB bug when querying sub documents with $in (working when querying root doc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have been trying this for a while now, and I came to the conclusion that it must be a bug in the mongo driver or something, but it makes no sense to me.

Models:

```
class Container
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :subs

  ...
end

class Sub
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :container

  references_and_referenced_in_many :stuffs

  ...
end
```

This allows me to do queries like this:

```
Container.where(:'subs.stuff_ids' => BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'))
```

or

```
Container.where(:'subs.stuff_ids'.in => [BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'), BSON::ObjectId('yyyy')])
```

All of this works fine, and give proper results.

Which means that those queries should give me access to the sub documents matching:

```
Container.subs.where(:stuff_ids => BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'))
```

=> Works, returns the list of proper subs

BUT

```
Container.subs.where(:stuff_ids.in => [BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'), BSON::ObjectId('yyyy')])
```

=> ALWAYS returns 0 subs... it makes no sense since the same query on the "containers" returns a proper list of containers with subs matching, but querying the subs from a given "container" never works with using "$in"

ps:

this is on: Rails 3.0.10, Mongoid 2.2.0 and Mongo Driver: 1.4.0

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in mongodb & its drivers. This is how it designed to work

```
   db.container.find({'subs.stuffids : {$in : [xx,yyy]}'})
```

this is the equivalent of

```
  Container.where(:'subs.stuff_ids'.in => [BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'), BSON::ObjectId('yyyy')])
```

But

```
Container.subs.where(:stuff_ids.in => [BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'), BSON::ObjectId('yyyy')])
```

You are querying the embedded doc as the normal document.This is totally wrong, And this will work fine if you define the relation has_many instead embeds_many.Because has_many stores the subs in a separate document and add referencing ids in other document like relational foreign keys.

Comment: Well I don't think you are right. I realize that the "stuffs" are not embedded documents, but I am not querying on stuffs attributes. Within each subs there is an actual array containing the ids of the referenced stuffs. And this is on that array that I am trying to perform the query. If what you said was true, I should not be able to perform the first query (Container.subs.where(:stuff_ids => BSON::ObjectId('xxxx'))) which works just fine. I really think the issue is relating to the  $in attribute. But I don't know if this is a mongoid issue or mongodb, I would think mongoid... but not sure

Comment: @Alex, **I realize that the "stuffs" are not embedded documents** , are you kidding me.. then whats **embeds_many :subs** means in your Container document..

Comment: first of all, no need for that tone. Second: stuffs != subs !! There are 3 models at play here, Container that embeds_mabt subs and Subs that contain a Array listing IDs of a third model Stuff. I haven't details the contents of the model Stuff as it's totally not relevant for the case since we are only concerned of with the Stuff IDs.

Comment: Yeah right i misunderstood. But my answer is perfectly makes sense. because i was saying subs as embedded docs.

Comment: Then I don't understand, because in mongoid one can always query embedded docs as "root" docs as long as you are accessing them from the root doc. Why would one of the query work and not the other ? Does not make sense to me. How do you "select" the sub-document you want then if you can't query the sub-collection ?

Comment: Can you please clarify me one thing.. is Sub a embedded document?? did you add embedded_in :container relation in Sub doc?

Comment: Yes Sub is embedded doc, and I added the embedded_in properly, forgot to write it up in the stackoverflow question though, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Nick Hoffman on the Mongoid Google Group (http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/9e07de1f3f04d1ef)

It works in 2.3.3, so I recommend upgrading from 2.2.0 :

```
class Parent 
  include Mongoid::Document 

  embeds_many :children 
end 

class Child 
  include Mongoid::Document 

  embedded_in :parent 

  has_and_belongs_to_many :others, :inverse_of => nil 
end 

class Other 
  include Mongoid::Document 
end 

Parent.delete_all 
Other.delete_all 

o1 = Other.create 
o2 = Other.create 
p = Parent.new 
p.children.new :others => [o1] 
p.children.new 
p.children.new :others => [o1, o2] 
p.save 

Parent.first.children.where(:other_ids.in => [o1.id, o2.id]).count 
=> 1
```

require 'mongoid/version' 
Mongoid::VERSION 
=> "2.3.3"